# Sorting a List of Lists with multiple criteria (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

For an assignment I have to create my own sorting algorithm to sort a list containing football scores.

The information is formatted as follows (with multiple sublists like this):

```
['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18]
```

First it should be sorted according to index 8, then if the numbers for index 8 are the same it should be sorted according to index 7, etcetera

I've managed to sort it according to index 8, but got stuck after that. So I'm using selection sort here:

```
def Sorting(List, sortVar):

    for index in range(len(List)):
        cur_pos = stats[index][sortVar]
        high = List[index]
        loc = index

        for i in range(index,len(List)):
            if stats[i][sortVar] > cur_pos:
                cur_pos = List[i][sortVar]
                high = List[i]
                loc = i

        temp = List[index]
        List[index] = high
        List[loc] = temp


    print("")
    print(List)
    return List
```

And then after this I've tried some things but gotten stuck. Might be a really simple question, but I'm really struggling. Thanks!

Edit: I've seen some posts explaining this, but I didn't understand them and they all used inbuilt sorting functions, which I'm not allowed to do...

Comment: It's unclear what you want from us here. What exactly is the desired input and output? What sorting algorithm do you want to implement? I assume you want to avoid Python builtin `sorted()`/`list.sort`?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `sort` or `sorted` with a tailored `key`?

Comment: @EricDuminil: *I have to create my own sorting algorithm*. Sounds ilke "nope".

Comment: Reverse all sublists, sort normally, re-reverse each sublist.

Comment: The input should be a list with 32 sublists of the form `['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18] `. The output should be this list sorted first on index 8, then if entries for index 8 are the same for index 1, etcetera. (Sorry hope this is clear, I'm very new to programming) I want to implement a sorting algorithm as the one I put in the original post, which they called: "selection sort" in my lectures. I cannot use `sort` or `sorted`. I hope this is a bit clearer @Chris_Rands? So in the end we want to know which country would have the highest rating.

Comment: `['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18], ['Spain', 6, 6, 0, 1, 8, 2, 6, 18]`
Netherlands would be above Spain, because the index 8 is the same, but index 1 is smaller for Spain.

Comment: @erip Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: If you use Python's own `sort`, the result is stable and performance non-pathological for almost-sorted lists.  To implement tie-breakers you can just sort multiple times using each key.  If you have to roll you own I don't think you can get much better result unless specially tailored for your data.

Comment: @Jayk Sure. Let's take your example with Netherlands and Spain. Reverse them both: `[[18, 6, 6, 12, 1, 0, 6, 7, 'Netherlands'], [18, 6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 6, 6, 'Spain']]`. Then sort them lexicographically: `[[18, 6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 6, 6, 'Spain'], [18, 6, 6, 12, 1, 0, 6, 7, 'Netherlands']]`. Then re-reverse each list: `[['Spain', 6, 6, 0, 1, 8, 2, 6, 18], ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18]]`.

Comment: @EricDuminil if I was allowed to use the python `sort`, how would that work? (Might as well learn something new, even if I'm not allowed to use it in this case (: )

Comment: `sorted(scores, key=lambda l: l[::-1])` should do. Basically, sort lists by their reversed values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Who knows? It's hard to tell how loose the definition of `own sorting algorithm` is.

Comment: Which methods are you allowed to use? If no builtin `sort` is allowed, you'd have to write a basic sort (e.g. bubble-sort) for single elements before you go on to lists and reversed lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [basic bubble sort](http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/01/basic-sorting-algorithms-implemented-in-python/):

```
def bubble_sort(items):
    """ Implementation of bubble sort """
    for i in range(len(items)):
        for j in range(len(items) - 1 - i):
            if items[j] > items[j + 1]:
                items[j], items[j + 1] = items[j + 1], items[j]     # Swap!
```

Here's a modified bubble sort. It just reverses both items before comparing them. Both compared elements must understand `[::-1]`:

```
def modified_bubble_sort(items):
    for i in range(len(items)):
        for j in range(len(items) - 1 - i):
            # Reverse the lists before comparing them
            if items[j][::-1] > items[j + 1][::-1]:
                items[j], items[j + 1] = items[j + 1], items[j]     # Swap!
```

It's not efficient because bubble sort is O(n**2) and the modified version keeps on reversing the same lists, but it's quite clear and concise.

Here's a test:

```
scores = [
    ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 19],
    ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 19],
    ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 7, 18],
    ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18],
    ['Spain', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 7, 18]
]

modified_bubble_sort(scores)
print(scores)
```

Note that it modified the original list in place. It outputs:

```
[['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 18], ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 7, 18], ['Spain', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 7, 18], ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 19], ['Netherlands', 7, 6, 0, 1, 12, 6, 6, 19]]
```

Which is the same result as with:

```
print(sorted(scores, key=lambda l: l[::-1]))
```

Comment: Whoops, I lost track of my post, but thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @Jayk: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the easiest way (if you're allowed to use built-ins) is to reverse each sublist, sort numerically-lexicographically, then re-reverse each sublist.

```
def my_sort(l):
    # Reverse so you can sort numerically-lexicographically
    reversed_lists = [x[::-1] for x in l]

    # Sort "normally" (i.e., numerically-lexicographically)
    reversed_lists.sort()

    # Re-reverse each sublist so they fit your expected return format
    return [x[::-1] for x in reversed_lists]
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/HXOF/0).

If you're not allowed to use built-ins, you will need to design the sorting bit yourself, but the logic remains the same.

You could also just use the [`key`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) kwarg to sort the reverse sublists:

```
def my_sort(l):
    return list(sorted(l, key=lambda subl: subl[::-1]))
```

Comment: I see how this works for sorting it on the basis of the first sorting parameter. However, I'm do not see how I should implement this for tiebreakers with other criteria without changing the order of the whole list and thus neglecting the previous sorting parameter(s)?

Comment: @Jayk "Tie breakers" are handled naturally by sorting.

Comment: You can see this when you check in the interpreter: `[1, 2, 3] > [1, 2, 2]`
and `[1, 2, 3, 'Spain'] > [1, 2, 3, 'Netherlands']`.

Comment: How would you implement this when for the different indexes, there are different "rules". If the "tiebreaker" falls on say index 1 for Netherlands is smaller than for Spain, this means Netherlands goes up in ranking (change place in the list). But when the "tiebreaker" falls on index 2, the value that is bigger moves up in the list.

Comment: @Jayk That's what sorting _is_.